# Userpermission pivot-function is only accessible via the Auth class

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, pivot-table

I have a simple Userpermission System consisting of 3 tables: users, permissions and the pivot table permission_user.

This is the User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
    }

}
```

and here is the Permission Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permission extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'level', 'parentpermission',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }


}
```

Now when I try to get all the permissions of the currently logged in user with this:

```
 $user_permissions = Auth::user()->permissions()->get();
```

it works without problems.

But when I try to get another Users Permissions like this:

```
$user_permissions = User::where('id', '=', $userid)->permissions()->get();
```

I get the following error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::permissions does not exist.
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing `first()` here, since you can't get relations of a query builder object. Try this :

```
$user_permissions = User::where('id', '=', $userid)->first()->permissions()->get();
```

This `first()` will actually return `User` object, and then you can load its  relations.

Comment: Thank you very much - that was the problem! I think now I understand how it all works

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

simply you can just add `first()` method to get just one record and get it's permissions, try this:

```php
$user_permissions = User::where('id', '=', $userid)->first()->permissions;
```

> There's no need to use get() method, this will get all the user permissions directely

Answer (score 0):

Do this -

```
$user_permissions = User::find($userid)->permissions()->get();
```